# Bash's source command not working with a file curl'd from internet

Tags: bash, shell, url

I am trying to source a script file from the internet using curl, like this: `source <( curl url ); echo done` , and what I see is that 'done' is echoed *before* the curl even starts to download the file!

Here's the actual command and the output:

```
-bash-3.2# source <( curl --insecure https://raw.github.com/gurjeet/pg_dev_env/master/.bashrc ) ; echo done
done
-bash-3.2# % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 2833 100 2833 0 0 6746 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0
```

I am not too worried about 'done' being echoed before or after anything, I am particularly concerned why the source command wouldn't read and act on the script!

This command works as expected on my LinuxMint's bash, but not on the CentOS server's bash!

Comment: Sounds horribly insecure

Comment: I understand the security issue, that's why this line will never go into any scripts of mine.

This is just for the times when I am handed a bash shell for one-off diagnosis. I just want to setup my environment without having to muddy the server's .bashrc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At first, I failed to notice that you're using Bash 3.2. That version won't source from a process substitution, but later versions such as Bash 4 do.

You can save the file and do a normal source of it:

```
source /tmp/del
```

(to use the file from your comment)

Or, you can use `/dev/stdin` and a here-string and a quoted command substitution:

```
source /dev/stdin <<< "$(curl --insecure https://raw.github.com/gurjeet/pg_dev_env/master/.bashrc)"; echo done
```

Comment: Spot on analysis (yes, bash on my server is 3.2 and on my laptop is 4.x) and straightforward workaround.

Accepted as the correct answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
exec 69<> >(:);
curl url 1>&69;
source /dev/fd/69;
exec 69>&-;
```

This should force yer shell to wait for all data from the pipe. If that doesn't work this one will:

```
exec 69<> >(:);
{ curl url 1>&69 & } 2>/dev/null;
wait $!
source /dev/fd/69;
exec 69>&-;
```

Comment: FWIW, I downloaded the file and stored locally, and even cat'ing that didn't work! `source <( sleep 3 ; cat /tmp/del ) ; echo done` does not wait at all before showing 'done' output!

Still waiting for an explanation of the behaviour, and a proper fix/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
file=$(mktemp)
curl --insecure -o $file https://raw.github.com/gurjeet/pg_dev_env/master/.bashrc 
source $file
rm $file
```