# Use line from file as a command in bash

Tags: bash

If I have a file with three lines like this

```
line 1
line 2
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"user": "joe"}' localhost/api
```

How can I execute a third line as command in bash?

I tried

```
$(sed '3q;d' file)
```

and

```
`sed '3q;d' file`
```

but it seems like in both cases the command is only partly executed, I don't get the right result. Of course, calling curl directly works fine.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Does this work: `$(sed -n '3p' < file)`?

Comment: @robert, no, it doesn't. Follow the link above to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted expansion runs string-splitting and globbing, but not other stages of the parsing process. Thus, it doesn't honor quotes, redirections, or other expansions.

This is actually a Good Thing for security reasons -- think about what would happen if you had to worry about the string `$(rm -rf ~)` being present inside untrusted data that your scripts handle!

That said, if you entirely trust the contents of this file, you can use `eval` to run it through the entirety of the parsing process:

```
eval "$(sed '3q;d' file)"
```

Comment: Why `\`sed '3q;d' file\`` doesn't work? I tired it on simple command, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, the problem isn't extracting the 3rd line, the problem is *running the extracted value as a command*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, correct, it won't always work. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0):

How about running a `bash` subprocess, with the `-c` flag?

```
bash -c "$(sed '3q;d' file)"
```

Comment: Perfectly valid if the command being run doesn't need access to shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

From [Bash 4](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2001-11/msg00004.html) / [Bash 3.2(Mac)](https://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-80/bash/CHANGES.auto.html) or higher, you can source the file from a process substitution:

```
source <(sed '3q;d' file)
```

or shorter:

```
. <(sed '3q;d' file)
```

Comment: Some versions of bash used to have a bug with this. (We have a StackOverflow question about that bug -- I can try to dig it up).

Comment: ...ahh, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596123/why-source-command-doesnt-work-with-process-substitution-in-bash-3-2; unfortunately, due to Apple's refusal to ship GPLv3'd software, such releases are still in wide use.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, it looks like Apple's latest 3.2.x release is patched for this, so maybe it's more historical now than I was thinking. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Found in GNU Bash 2.05: "Startup files and files read with source or '.' are no longer required to be regular files."

Comment: The bug *definitely* existed long past 2.05. See the linked SO questions, which were asked about 3.2 builds.

Comment: And http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2006-01/msg00018.html is a mailing list thread from the 3.1 days.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right, I found a fix mentioned in [Bash 4.0rc1](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2009-01/msg00029.html) release notes.