# Process substitution to 'source' do not work on Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos

### Background

I have some project where project version is defined as macros in C header file.
I've found the way to fetch this data from a C header file and process that in some bash script on Mac OS.

### Problem

For some reason "Process substitution" doesn't work when I feed this data to a `source` command.

Here is test bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

VERSION_BUILD_FILE=$(dirname $0)/Somepath/Version.h

function parseNow() {
    gcc -E -dM "$VERSION_BUILD_FILE" | sed -E '{
        /^#define (VERSION_M|BUILD_NUMBER)/!d
        /#define[ \t]*[^ \t]*$/d
        s/[^ \t]*[ \t]*([^ \t]*)[ \t]*(.*)/\1=\2/
        /(""|\([^\)]*\))/d
    }'
}

function checkVersioVer() {
    echo "$VERSION_MAJOR.$VERSION_MINOR.$BUILD_NUMBER   milestone: $VERSION_MILESTONE"
}

checkVersioVer

echo parseNow result:
parseNow

echo "----"
echo "source parseNow"
source <(parseNow)
checkVersioVer

echo "----"
echo "copy parseNow then source tmp.txt"
cp <(parseNow) tmp.txt
source tmp.txt
rm tmp.txt
checkVersioVer
```

This produces this output:

```
..   milestone: 
parseNow result:
BUILD_NUMBER=1047
VERSION_MAJOR=1
VERSION_MILESTONE="v1.3"
VERSION_MINOR=3
----
source parseNow
..   milestone: 
----
copy parseNow then source tmp.txt
1.3.1047   milestone: v1.3
```

As you can see `source parseNow` part doesn't work but `copy parseNow` does work even though copy is performed with process substitution to a temporary file.

Here is a sample header:

```c
#define BUILD_NUMBER 1047
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 3
#define VERSION_MILESTONE "v1.3"
// other stuff
```

### Question

Why `source <(parseNow)` doesn't work (on Mac OS Mojave)?
Can I fix it somehow?
I wish I don't have to use temporary file to process this C header file. This is last resort.

`echo $BASH_VERSION` prints `3.2.57(1)-release`

Based on comments other aproches which do not work:

```
parseNow | source /dev/fd/0
source /dev/fd/0 < <(parseNow)
parseNow | source - # line 26: -: No such file or directory
source - < <(parseNow)
```

Comment: What is the bash version you are trying this on? This works on GNU bash, version 4.3

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION` prints `3.2.57(1)-release`

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of [Why source command doesn't work with process substitution in bash 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32596123/5291015) then. Can you try `source /dev/stdin <<<"$(parseNow)"`

Comment: cool this should do the job. Thanks @Inian

Comment: sadly on MacOS there is no `/dev/stdin`. I'm trying to find equivalent.

Comment: FreeBSD should have `/dev/fd/0`

Comment: I understand why this is closed as duplicate, but since this is MacOS not Linux, proposed workarounds do not work.

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? At least since 10.13.6, `/dev/stdin` is a symlink to `/dev/fd/0`.

Comment: ok autocomplete doesn't catches this symlink. `ls -al /dev/ | grep std` shows that `/dev/stdin` symlink is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596626/6770384), `source` does not work with process substitution in older bash versions.

However, since the workaround presented in the same answer doesn't seem to work for you, let me propose an alternative:

```
eval "$(parseNow)"
```

I know, I know, `eval` is bad and stuff but there really is no difference between `source /dev/stdin <<< "string"` and `eval "string"`.

<sub>Personally, I think booing `eval` but not all the other unsafe constructs is a double standard. There is a highly interesting blog post from the author of `shellcheck` on this issue:

[white collar eval: `[[ $var -eq 42 ]]` runs arbitrary code too](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=716)</sub>