# How do I copy and paste Bash without dollar signs?

Tags: bash, copy-paste

Suppose I have the following code in a StackOverflow response:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=main.py
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ python -m flask run
```

Is there an easy way to copy and paste this without the $ signs, so I can directly paste this into my terminal?

Comment: Paste it into `vim` then you can just whack off the first character [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55507361/2221001). At any rate you will have to put it into some text editor and manipulate (or hit the file with `sed` or something).

Comment: You might want to look at the `fc` command in conjunction with JNevill's suggestion.

Comment: In zsh, you can simply make a dollar function that serves as a pass-thru: `function $ { "$@" }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
. <( sed 's/^\$ //' <<'PASTE'
**paste here**
PASTE
)
```

Or, make that into a function:

```
undollar() { . <( sed 's/^\$ //' ); }
```

Than you use that like

```
$ undollar<hit enter>
<paste here>
<hit Ctrl+D>
```

Both of these approaches use the `.` command, so effects are seen in the current shell: for example with the commands you list, the FLASK_APP and FLASK_DEBUG environment variables remain in the shell.

---

As noted by Charles Duffy, old versions of bash cannot source a process substitution: see [Why source command doesn't work with process substitution in bash 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596123/why-source-command-doesnt-work-with-process-substitution-in-bash-3-2)

Comment: Note that some versions of bash have a bug when sourcing output from a process substitution -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596123/why-source-command-doesnt-work-with-process-substitution-in-bash-3-2