# Preserve quotes in YAML when using yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

Given `config.yaml`:

```
APP_ID: APP158
APP_NAME: "My Application"
```

And `process-config.sh` which reads the YAML entries and converts them to BASH syntax of `KEY=VALUE` in order to be set as environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

export $(yq e "to_entries | map(.key + \"=\" +  .value) | join(\" \")" config.yaml)

echo $APP_ID
echo $APP_NAME
```

The following output is produced:

```
APP158
My
```

How do I retain the quotes around `APP_NAME`'s values so that its value isn't truncated (as shown in output)?

Comment: If what you want is correct _shell_ quoting, not _YAML_ quoting, then you should ask for shell quoting, which is different from preserving YAML quoting. (For example, `"$(rm -rf ~)"` is safe/correct quoting in YAML, but it's absolutely _not_ safe in shell -- you would need to use single quotes, `'$(rm -rf ~)'`, there).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@sh` [encoder](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode) (available since [v4.31.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.31.1)) to quote a string so that it is interpretable by the shell:

```bash
yq e 'to_entries | map(.key + "=" + (.value | @sh)) | join(" ")'
```

```
APP_ID=APP158 APP_NAME=My' Application'
```

Note that since version 4.18.1, "yq's 'eval/e' command is the default command and no longers needs to be specified."

Comment: if you are suggesting this approach, do recommend not using the double-quote syntax for yq. It just makes it a quoting mess

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `to_entries` at all, just output the variables in a shell compatible format and have it exported at your shell.

For recent bash versions, use process-substitution `<(..)` technique to expose a FIFO, that source can read as a file input from.

```bash
set -a
source <(yq -o=shell config.yaml)
set +a
```

In older versions of bash, e.g. 3.2 (baked into macOS by default), exporting from source doesn't work directly, you can use a work-around as below (See [Why source command doesn't work with process substitution in bash 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32596123/5291015))

```bash
set -a
source /dev/stdin <<< $(yq -o=shell config.yaml)
set +a
```

The `-`/`+` flags around `a`, serve as a placeholder, within which newly created/modified variables are exported.

Comment: We don't want to shell-escape the whole string, just the value -- that is to say, we want something equivalent to `export key="value"` not `"export key=value"`

Answer (score 1):

In bash you could simply do:

```bash
$ IFS=, read -r ID NAME<<<$(yq e '[.APP_ID,.APP_NAME] | join(",")' config.yaml)
$ echo "$ID"
APP158
$ echo "$NAME"
My Application
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have issues with the overall concept. Assume that you successfully keep the quotes around `"My Application"`, the string you are trying to construct will do the same thing in Bash.

If you try:

```
bash-5.2$ export $(echo APP_NAME="My Application")
bash-5.2$ echo "$APP_NAME"
My
```

You can see that adding `"My Application"` in quotes does not fix the problem if you are just using `export`.

However, if you use `source` to read a crafted export command, you can get what you are looking for:

```
bash-5.2$ source <(echo "export APP_NAME=My\ Application")
bash-5.2$ echo "$APP_NAME"
My Application
```

The easiest way to do this might be in Ruby or Perl or jq or yq where you can escape shell meaningful words.

An example in Ruby (I assume Perl, jq, yq are the same result...):

```
source <(ruby -r yaml -r shellwords -e '
puts YAML.load($<.read).map{|k,v| "export #{k}=#{Shellwords.escape(v)}" }
' file)
```

Then:

```
bash-5.2$ echo "$APP_ID"
APP158
bash-5.2$ echo "$APP_NAME"
My Application
```

Comment: Both yq and jq have shell-quoting facilities equivalent to the Ruby `Shellwords.escape`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: True, but the string the OP is *trying* to construct is the problem...

Comment: Granted, I spend more time with jq than yq, but it's not obvious to me why it's a problem; in jq, I'd write `to_entries[] | "export \(.key)=\(.value|@sh)"`, escaping only the right-hand side just as your Ruby code does; pmf's answer implies that that's possible in yq as well.